# How can I reuse a Subscriber between two Observables (RxJava)

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

In order to not repeat myself, I want to re-use a `Subscriber` variable between two observables. How do you do accomplish this? My current code below does not work, because after the subscriber is used once, it is unsubscribed and no longer works again. If I `new` a `Subscriber` instead of reusing a variable, my subscription works. I don't want to write the same code twice, if possible.

```
public class HomePresenter extends BasePresenter<HomeView> {
    ArticleRepo articleRepo;

    @Inject
    public HomePresenter(ArticleRepo articleRepo) {
        this.articleRepo = articleRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable PresenterBundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
    }


    public void onEvent(ArticleCategoryClickedEvent event) {
        Timber.v("Adapter position clicked at position: '%d'", event.getAdapterPosition());
        view.launchArticleActivity(event.getArticleCategory());
    }

    public void onEvent(SeabeeOnlineExternalLinkClickedEvent event) {

    view.launchExternalLink(event.getSeabeeOnlineExternalLink());
}

public void loadArticleImages() {
    articleRepo.getArticleBuckets()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
}

public void refreshData() {
    articleRepo.refreshAndSaveArticles()
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<ArticleEntity>, Observable<List<ImageArticleCategoryEntity>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<ImageArticleCategoryEntity>> call(List<ArticleEntity> articleEntityList) {
                    return articleRepo.getArticleBuckets();
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);

}

final Subscriber<List<ImageArticleCategoryEntity>> subscriber = new Subscriber<List<ImageArticleCategoryEntity>>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Timber.v("Loading article images complete!");
        view.hideLoadingAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Timber.e("Error loading article images", e);
        Log.e("tag", "Error loading article images", e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(List<ImageArticleCategoryEntity> integerImageArticleCategoryEntityHashMap) {
        view.loadArticleImages(integerImageArticleCategoryEntityHashMap);
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `Subscriber` should not be reused. It will not work because it is a `Subscription` and once unsubscribed it is done.

Use an `Observer` instead if you want to reuse it.

[source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1535#issuecomment-50648178)

Comment: A Subscriber IS an observer. public abstract class Subscriber<T> implements Observer<T>, Subscription

Comment: Observer gets wrapped into a new subscriber instance when subscribe() is called with it as argument so this created subscriber is not reused.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse your subscriber, you just need to create an actual class out of it.

```
private static class MySubscriber extends Subscriber<List<ImageArticleCategoryEntity>> {...}

Subscriber<> subscriber1 = new MySubscriber();
Subscriber<> subscriber2 = new MySubscriber();
```

And there you go.